# How can I easily call an IronPython function from VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, function, opencv, ironpython, emgucv

I am struggling with this program which uses emgucv(an opencv wrapper for .net) for about 2 weeks. The problem is unfortunately not programming, but setting up emgucv in such a way that it works. I didn't manage to do so for vb.net so I tried doing it for ironpython(because I know python too). Emgucv seems to work perfectly when using ironpython, so I created a function that takes an image as an argument and analyses it in the way I want, returning another image with the results in it. The problem is I want to call this function, giving it the image argument(it could be a string containing the path) from within VB.net and become another string containing the result image as return. I later plan to package that project in a setup so I can redistribute it.

So I am asking you guys: Do you know an easy way to call an IronPython function in VB.net in such a way so I can also package the whole project and redistribute it to people?

Thank you so much for reading this and it would be great if you could also help me with my problem! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While IronPython is not my expertise I am well versed in EMGU and its applications. If you insist in using IronPython the following website clearly shows how to pass a string to an [IronPython Class.](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2008/08/14/calling-ironpython-functions-from-net.aspx)

The following code is taken from the link and is not my own:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting
Imports IronPython.Hosting
Imports IronPython.Runtime.Types

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim helloWorld As New HelloWorldVB()
        Console.WriteLine(helloWorld.HelloWorld("Maurice"))

    Dim runtime As ScriptRuntime = PythonEngine.CurrentEngine.Runtime
    Dim scope As ScriptScope = runtime.ExecuteFile("HelloWorld.py")
    Dim pythonType As PythonType = scope.GetVariable(Of PythonType)("HelloWorldIronPython")
    helloWorld = CType(runtime.Operations.Call(pythonType), HelloWorldVB)
    Console.WriteLine(helloWorld.HelloWorld("Maurice"))

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
End Module
```

I would follow the tutorial from the link but the important code is bellow as this imports the require runtime information for IronPython:

```
**Imports Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting
Imports IronPython.Hosting
Imports IronPython.Runtime.Types**
```

&

```
 **Dim runtime As ScriptRuntime = PythonEngine.CurrentEngine.Runtime
    Dim scope As ScriptScope = runtime.ExecuteFile("HelloWorld.py")
    Dim pythonType As PythonType = scope.GetVariable(Of PythonType)("HelloWorldIronPython")
    helloWorld = CType(runtime.Operations.Call(pythonType), HelloWorldVB)
    Console.WriteLine(helloWorld.HelloWorld("Maurice"))**
```

Obviously  Console.WriteLine(helloWorld.HelloWorld("Maurice")) would be corrected to:

Dim result_location As String = helloWorld.HelloWorld("Maurice")

Where "Maurice" would be the string containing your image location.

Now I have to ask about the problems you were having setting up EMGU in visual studio I know it can be frustrating to do especially to people who are new to it. If you would like I would be happy to help you set it up properly. The reason I ask is since you are providing this to and end user your code could be more efficient without calling IronPython. Especially since each process will require reading and writing from the hard drive.

To start: I will assume that you have included References to Emgu.CV, Emgu.CV.UI, and EMGU.Util in your project. But it is essential that you add "opencv_core220.dll", "opencv_imgproc220.dll" files directly to your project and ensure in the properties window that the 'Copy to Output' option is set to "Copy always". If it isn't you will get errors of not a having the image in the right format etc. You only really need these two .dll  to read images in and access the data etc you may need others for .avi movies for example. Note that these two .dll must now be distributed with your project for it to work.

To note this may change depending if your using a 64 bit machine or a 32 bit machine but the 64 bit EMGU version will not run on X86 machines. You must also ensure that your target platform is correct in Visual Studio.

I hope this helps you,

Cheers
Chris

Comment: Wow, Chris! That is a great reply you gave me! Very detailed! I will check your link out later as now I can't, but it seems like it will work. Anyways, about the emgu errors I get, whenever I try to create an image in visual basic using this statement:Dim img As New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)("Proba1.jpg") I get an exception stating that "The type initialized for Emgu.Cv.CvInvoke threw an exception. Also, visual studio opens a new tab containing Image.cs in it. This happens every time I try to access the Image class from Emgu.CV. Might it be because it's a windows forms application? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi sorry about the late reply I was of on holiday, "The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception." Is usually down to opencv_core220.dll not being available in the output directory. If you dig down through the error by going Actions: View Detail... the InnerException will probably read {"Unable to load DLL 'opencv_core220': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}  or similar like I said you have to add "opencv_core220.dll", "opencv_imgproc220.dll" files directly to your project [continues]

Comment: [] then in the solution explorer select each file and change the "Copy to Output" properties option (in the properties window) to Copy always. This should solve the problem while annoying the problem stems down to EMGU only being a wrapper so it still needs the original OpenCv class files there to work with. I hope this solves the problem Cheers

Comment: Just in case I've just noted there is another time this error may become apparent in this case the InnerException will read {"An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"}. This is down to the target platform I tend to use the 64bit compiled version of EMGU and because of this you can only target x64 platforms (I am unsure if this applies to x86) but this is an easy fix by changing the project properties "Build" tab options. Take Care

Comment: Thanks Chris! That problem is solved! But now I get another exception when trying to run the program, saying: "Unable to load DLL 'cvextern': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)". I have added cvextern.dll to the project, that didn't solve my problem. I tried to add a reference to  cvextern.dll aswell, but it turned out it is not a valid COM component. Thanks for your answer and help and I hope you had a great time in your holiday!

Comment: Hi Calin, yes unfortunately you can't add them as references (this would be much easier', I will assumed you corrected cvextern.dll's properties to 'Copy Always'. Chances are it's after yet another .dll which is derived from this particular class. The two I previously mentioned are the bare minimum required to load images and access it's data. There are two ways you can go about solving the problem,

Comment: 1) Add all the dll and remove one by one until you break it again (I hate this method but it works and if you are not re-distributing the program you don't really have to worry about deleting unwanted ones)         2) Try adding these dll...  "opencv_ml220.dll" ,  "opencv_highgui220"  ,  and of course "cvextern.dll"  with all the properties set to copy always these cover a majority of functions required without knowing exactly what functions you calling I can't tell you exactly which ones. I afraid I've yet to find an easier option. Cheers

Comment: Thanks Chris! Sorry for the late answer. That seemed to have fixed my problem. Thanks a lot for your time and effort!